# Apollo client: Making optimistic updates while creation is still in progress

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, optimistic-ui

I want to be able to do updates on an object while it is still being created.

For example: Say I have a to-do list where I can add items with names. I also want to be able to edit names of items.

Now say a user with a slow connection creates an item. In that case I fire off a create item mutation and optimistically update my UI. That works great. So far no problem

Now let's say the create item mutation is taking a bit of time due to a slow network. In that time, the user decides to edit the name of the item they just created. For an ideal experience:

1. The UI should immediately update with the new name
2. The new name should eventually be persisted in the server

I can achieve #2 by waiting for the create mutation to finish (so that I can get the item ID), then making an update name mutation. But that means parts of my UI will remain unchanged until the create item mutation returns and the optimistic response of the update name mutation kicks in. This means #1 won't be achieved.

So I'm wondering how can I achieve both #1 and #2 using Apollo client.

Note: I don't want to add spinners or disable editing. I want the app to feel responsive even with a slow connection.

Comment: do optimistic update like in the case of creation. In case of updates, keep the mutation ready and do it in background once the create operation is completed and you have the id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to the server you can implement `upsert` operations, and you can reduce all queries to the such one:

```
mutation {
  upsertTodoItem(
    where: {
      key: $itemKey # Some unique key generated on client
    }
    update: {
      listId: $listId
      text: $itemText
    }
    create: {
      key: $itemKey
      listId: $listId
      text: $itemText
    }
  ) {
    id
    key
  }
}
```

So you will have a sequence of identical mutations differing only in variables. An optimistic response accordingly, can be configured to this one mutation. On the server you need to check if an item with such a `key` already exists and create or update an item respectively.

Additionally you might want to use [apollo-link-debounce](https://github.com/helfer/apollo-link-debounce) to reduce number of requests when user is typing.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to achieve your desired effect is to actually drop optimistic updates in favor of managing the component state yourself. I don't have the bandwidth at the moment to write out a complete example, but your basic component structure would look like this:

```
<ApolloConsumer>
  {(client) => (
    <Mutation mutation={CREATE_MUTATION}>
      {(create) => (
        <Mutation mutation={EDIT_MUTATION}>
          {(edit) => (
            <Form />
          )}
        </Mutation>        
      )}
    </Mutation>
  )}
</ApolloConsumer>
```

Let's assume we're dealing with just a single field -- `name`. Your `Form` component would start out with an initial state of

```
{ name: '', created: null, updates: null }
```

Upon submitting, the Form would do something like:

```
onCreate () {
  this.props.create({ variables: { name: this.state.name } })
    .then(({ data, errors }) => {
      // handle errors whichever way
      this.setState({ created: data.created })
      if (this.state.updates) {
        const id = data.created.id
        this.props.update({ variables: { ...this.state.updates, id } })
      }
    })
    .catch(errorHandler)
}
```

Then the edit logic looks something like this:

```
onEdit () {
  if (this.state.created) {
    const id = this.state.created.id
    this.props.update({ variables: { name: this.state.name, id } })
      .then(({ data, errors }) => {
        this.setState({ updates: null })
      })
      .catch(errorHandler)
  } else {
    this.setState({ updates: { name: this.state.name } })
  }
}
```

In effect, your edit mutation is either triggered immediately when the user submits (since we got a response back from our create mutation already)... or the changes the user makes are persisted and then sent once the create mutation completes.

That's a very rough example, but should give you some idea on how to handle this sort of scenario. The biggest downside is that there's potential for your component state to get out of sync with the cache -- you'll need to ensure you handle errors properly to prevent that.

That also means if you want to use this form for *just* edits, you'll need to fetch the data out of the cache and then use that to populate your initial state (i.e. `this.state.created` in the example above). You can use the `Query` component for that, just make sure you don't render the actual `Form` component until you have the `data` prop provided by the `Query` component.